# Can't get Uri Data from Deep Link

Tags: android, parameters, uri, intentfilter, deep-linking

I want to be redirected from the browser to my App, so I use the following code for my Activity in the Manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="fivos"
                android:host="book"
                />
        </intent-filter>
```

// Accepts URIs that begin with "fivos://book"

There are also some parameters in the Uri that the browser sends (For example fivos://book?username=george).
In the Activity to which I am redirected, I use the following code to get the Uri but the parameters don't seem to exist in the Uridata object, except the scheme and the host

```
Uri URIdata = getIntent().getData();        
if(URIdata != null){
        String scheme = URIdata.getScheme();
        String host = URIdata.getHost();
        List params = URIdata.getPathSegments();
        String username = params.get(0).toString();
    }
```

Am I missing something in my manifest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I use the following code to get the Uri but the parameters don't seem to exist in the Uridata object, except the sheme and the host

The stuff after the `?` in a URL or `Uri` are the query parameters, which you can retrieve from the `Uri` via methods [like `getQuery()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getQuery()).

Comment: I cleared the browser's data and repeated the procedure. The Uridata object now is as the browser sent it, containing the parameter. 
@CommonsWare thanks for your immediate answer!